# Can react-admin be deployed as a static site?

Tags: react-admin, static-site

I wish to deploy a `react-admin` application as a static site - running without a server component.  This data browsing app would use the `ra-data-fakerest` on a read-only slug of JSON.

Examples of deploying this would be to a GitHub Pages site, or a dumb memory stick.

Since `react-admin` is written in React/Typescript it must get trans-piled before running, presumably into a `build` folder.  So, am I right in thinking I could just deploy the `build` folder?

(also grateful for any lessons-learned on this subject).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can. The react-admin demo (https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/) is indeed a static site. What is deployed is just the built version of https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/demo.

The react-admin codesandbox is another example of that: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/simple

Comment: Hello there @françois-zaninotto thanks for that. I've been having a play. It appears that to open index.html straight from the file browser, I needed to change all of the "\" at the start of URL addresses to ".\".